# Binding to DependencyProperty works only with "MyValue" and not "{Binding PropertyHoldingMyValue}"

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, dependency-properties

I am creating a custom "PageHeaderControl" UserControl, with a header property:

```
 public partial class PageHeaderControl: UserControl
 {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Header",
                        typeof(string), typeof(PageHeaderControl),
                        new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string Header
    {
        get { return GetValue(HeaderProperty) as string; }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

 }
```

In the XAML for that control, I have:

```
<sdk:Label Content="{Binding Header,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Now for the problem:** When I create the control, binding it only works to do this:

```
<my:PageHeaderControl Header="This is my page header" />
```

And it does not work to do this, where `PageHeader` is the property in my ViewModel holding the header value:

```
<my:PageHeaderControl Header="{Binding PageHeader,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I thought maybe my properties were messed up, but this also works:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PageHeader,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Any ideas as to what the problem could be!

**Thanks so much!!!**

**Edit:**

In my ViewModel, PageHeader is this:

```
private string _pageHeader = "This is my page header";
public string PageHeader
{
    get
    {
        return _pageHeader;
    }
    set
    {
        _pageHeader = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("PageHeader");
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

When I put a breakpoint inside the "get" for my `PageHeader` property, it does not get hit AT ALL, unless I add in the TextBlock...

Comment: have you tried using the HeaderedContentControl from the [toolkit](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/11/11/silverlight-toolkit-headeredcontentcontrol-amp-headereditemscontrol.aspx)? This is what it is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to bind a property of an element within your control's XAML markup to the property of the control itself.

If this is the case, see if the following helps you.

PageHeaderControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TryElementBinding.PageHeaderControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
x:Name = "MyControl"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, ElementName=MyControl}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

PageHeaderControl.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class PageHeaderControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(PageHeaderControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string Header
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(HeaderProperty) as string;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public PageHeaderControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _pageHeader = "This is my page header";

    public string PageHeader
    {
        get
        {
            return _pageHeader;
        }
        set
        {
            _pageHeader = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PageHeader"));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <my:PageHeaderControl Header="{Binding PageHeader, Mode=TwoWay}"></my:PageHeaderControl>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused and I think you missed the syntax of Binding inline expression.

after "{Binding" comes Path to your property. Is "PageHeader" is a path to your property?!

I think you mean this:

```
<my:PageHeader Header="{Binding PageHeader, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding PageHeader, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The problem is that Binding expression only works when you set the value of property using SetValue method and notify the parent DependencyObject that specific property has changed! 
You should use a DependencyProperty to have TwoWay Binding on it, OR implement System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChange interface in your class and notify the Binding object manually by calling PropertyChanged event in the interface.

The definition of PageHeader property should be like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PageHeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PageHeader", typeof(string), typeof(YOUROWNER), new PropertyMetadata(""));

public string PageHeader
{
    get { return GetValue(PageHeaderProperty) as string; }
    set { SetValue(PageHeaderProperty, value); }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: According to the question, the binding to `PageHeader` in the `TextBlock` does work, though. I'm assuming there's a property in the OP's view model named `PageHeader` that contains the text to show in the `my:PageHeader` control (?)

Comment: PageHeader is the path to the property in my ViewModel, sorry I wasn't more clear.

Comment: It'd be better if you include the definition of PageHeader property in your ViewModel.

Comment: But the DependencyProperty is in my control, not my view model... Is there not a way to keep DPs out of the view model?

Comment: If your target object for TwoWay binding is your model, then it should either implement the mentioned interface or be a DependencyObject. But if your target object for TwoWay binding is your control, you should change the binding expressions and bind them to the property of your Control. I think your problem is the matter of model and it's not a technical issue. Cheers

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why the present setup allows me to bind  to the TextBlock just fine, but not to my Control.  Doesn't that suggest that the problem is with my control ("PageHeaderControl")?

Comment: If you are using MVVM model to present data on the interface, your model should be a DependencyObject and every property on interface should be targeted on the model object as it says. You can have one model object and many views. I hope it helps you. Cheers

Comment: So there is no way to just store the title in the ViewModel (which is not a dependencyobject)?

Comment: Yes it is, as I said, you can implement INotifyProperyChanged interface in your ViewModel and simulate DependencyObject notification manually by firing PropertyChange event of the interface.

Comment: Aren't I already doing that, though? My PageHeader in my ViewModel does fire the PropertyChanged event.  When I bind to this control, though, it doesn't even try to get it...

Comment: Have you implemented the mentioned interface by the ViewModel object?

Comment: Yes. I have.  I have all the other properties set up the same way and they all bind just fine to other controls.  Even this property binds just fine to every control other than `my:PageHeaerControl`

Comment: Change the PageHeader property to dependency property like what I wrote and see what happens, let me know.